# Which value of HDD avgqu-sz is critical?

Tags: hard-drive, performance-counters

[This is my graph of HDD avgqu-sz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEFS9.png) from different app machines: [image: avgqu-sz]
App caches data in memory and every n minutes are data flushed to filesystem + every m minutes are data (re)loaded from filesystem in memory. That's the reason of the spikes. Block devices utilization during these spikes is 80-95%.

**Q: Do I need to worry about my disks performance? How to interpret this graph  - is OK or not OK?  Do I need to optimize something?**

- Yes, I have pretty high spikes ~1k, but then queue size is ~1 => one day avg is ~16 - I don't know If I can be happy with this avg value
- Yes, I know what metric avgqu-sz means
- Yes, I've optimized my filesystems for high IOps (noatime, nodirtime)

Comment: It's `avgqu-sz` - for "average queue size". It also says so in your graph, although I can see how easy it is to mistake a "q" for a "g" with some fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Yes, I know what metric avggu-sz means
> >     That means you know that generally data flows like this

```
     app --> bio layer --> I/O Scheduler --> Driver --> Disks
                           nr_requests                  queue_depth
```

This is just a general overview and not covering everything.As long as nr_requests remains the queue_Depth,I/O will pass quickly.The issue starting arising when these requests exceeding the queue depth and the I/O start helding in scheduler layer.

Looking at your graphs I would highly suggest 
1: check the disk having high peaks
2: Try to change the value of nr_requests and queue_depth to see if it helps
3: Change the scheduler in your test environment(as your data here doesn't contain merge request(read/write)..so I cant comment)

```
                /sys/block/<your disk drive sda,sdb...>/queue/nr_requests (io scheduler)
                /sys/block/<your disk drive sda,sdb...>/device/queue_depth (driver)
```

Comment: Thx for comment Prashant. Here is my graph of HDD rrqm/s (bad label on the graph rwrqm/s) wrqm/s  r/s w/s http://i.imgur.com/iHgXPWa.png from different app machines. My disk values queue_depth: 32, nr_requests: 128, scheduler: noop anticipatory deadline [cfq]. I'l try to tweak these values. Any recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

An average queue size of more than 1,000 requests is trouble unless you are running an array with hundreds of disks exposed as a single device.

From your graph however I would argue that most of your spikes are either measurement or graphing artefacts - your data looks like it is being collected in 5-minute intervals, yet the spikes do have a width of basically zero - very unusual. You should take a look at the raw data as collected by `sar` or displayed by `iostat` in near-realtime to rule that out. If you still see queue sizes of more than 30 requests per spindle used, check back here with the data.

Comment: Yes, data are collected every 5 minutes, but collection period is also 5 minute (So I collect output, which is similar to iostat -xd 300 10). Only the busiest machine has 1 minute collection period.